# C- Double free error when trying to delete first node in linked list

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, linked-list

I'm trying to write a delete function that deletes nodes from a linked list. The structure and function definition are below:

```
struct dog{
    int number;
    char dog_name[NAME_LEN+1];
    char owner_last_name[NAME_LEN+1];
    char breed[NAME_LEN+1];
    struct dog *next;
};

struct dog *delete_from_list(struct dog *dogs)
{
  struct dog *cur, *prev;
  int delete_number;

  printf("\nEnter the patient number of the dog you want to delete: ");
  scanf("%d", &delete_number);

  for(cur = dogs, prev = NULL; cur != NULL && (cur->number != delete_number);
      prev = cur, cur = cur->next)
   ;

  if(cur == NULL)
  {
    printf("Dog not found.\n"); /*dog not found in list*/   
    return dogs;         
  }else if(prev==NULL)
  {
    dogs = dogs->next; /*dog now points to the second node*/ 
  }else
    prev->next = cur->next;  /*dog is in another node*/

  printf("Deleted: Dog name: %s, Breed: %s,  Owner's last name: %s\n",
           cur->dog_name, cur->breed, cur->owner_last_name);
  free(cur);
  return dogs;
}
```

When I run the program, the delete function works until I try to delete the first node. I used my debugger and found out that `dogs = dogs->next;` is where the error occurs, but I don't understand why that's causing a problem if I move the new head of `dogs` to the second node. Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: The problem might be in the call to this function.  In the caller, are you sure you're updating the list head with the value this function returns?  I.e. `dogs = delete_from_list(dogs);`

Comment: When I call the function, I have a pointer, `*dog_list`, that points to dogs. This is what I have `delete_from_list(dog_list);`.

Comment: Debugger...............

Comment: That's your problem.  You call the function to delete the first element.  The function correctly returns the new list head, but the caller discards it, so it's now pointing to the node that was deleted.  Just change it to `dog_list = delete_from_list(dog_list);` and the problem will disappear.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your comment, you're calling this as:

```
delete_from_list(dog_list);
```

This doesn't work in the case where the first element is deleted, since in that case `delete_from_list` will return the new list head (which was formerly the second element of the list), but `dog_list` in the caller will still point to the now-deleted former first element.  All you need to do to fix this is change this to:

```
dog_list = delete_from_list(dog_list);
```

That way `dog_list` will be updated in the caller and will no longer point to a deleted list element.